# Passing data-id to bootstrap modal and use it iframe url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display map in bootstrap Modal. i have list of records which contain location link. on click location its will show the map location in modal window. i successfully passed the value to modal window. but unable to use in iframe src link. below is my code.

```
<a href="#myMapModal" class="btn fblack" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?=$row['lat']?>,<?=$row['lng']?>">Location on Map</a>
```

and my jquery

```
<script>
$('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var location = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
    $(this).find('#latlng').text(location);
});
</script>
```

i am trying to put the return value in a url

```
<iframe width="570" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=#latlng&amp;key=xxxxxxxxxxx"></iframe>
```

i given `q=#latlng`

i could able to print by using `<div id="latlng"></div>`

but i am unable to use in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script, learn more about the google api

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
    $('#myMapModal').$('.bs-example-modal-lg').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var location = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
       var newUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=1234&center='+location;
        console.log(newUrl);
      $(this).find('iframe').attr('src',newUrl);
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: sorry i am new to jquery  i dont know how to use it. in the above code in the question

Comment: am i required to do any thing with my iframe <iframe width="570" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=#latlng&amp;key=xxxxxxxxxxx"></iframe>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106539/discussion-between-asesha-george-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

what i did to make it work.

```
<script>
$('#myMapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var location = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'map-list.php', //Here you will fetch records 
            data :  'rowid='+ location, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('#fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

on map-list.php

```
 <?php
    //Include database connection
    if($_POST['rowid']) {
        $eveid = $_POST['rowid']; //escape string

        ?>

        <iframe width="570" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<?=$eveid?>&amp;key=AIzaSyCoqMKgHRLWPQAwjGq0dzRhSg6e4UlrgE4"></iframe> 
    <?      
 }
?>
```

in modal body

```
<div id="fetched-data"></div>
```